# Are there any compact subspaces in $\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis

I am confused about compact *subspaces* in $\mathbb R^n.$ Are there any examples of subspaces which are compact in $\mathbb R^n?$

Comment: What is a "subspace"? Vector subspace? Metric subspace? Which one?

Comment: Any closed and bounded subset is a compact subspace.

Comment: Subspace is very overloaded terminology in mathematics. It can mean vector subspace or topological subspace for instance. Which do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

According to Heine-Borel Theorem, closed and bounded subspaces of $\Bbb R^n$ are compact. For example, the closed unit ball
$$\small B^n=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)|x_1^2+x_2^2+...+x_n^2\leq1\}$$
or the closed unit cube
$$\small C^n=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)|x_i^2\leq\frac12,\, i=1,2,...,n\}$$
are compact subspaces. You can produce many examples.

But there are no compact linear subspace except the trivial subspace $\{0\}$. Since they are unbounded. To see this take a non-zero vector from this linear subspace. By multiplying with big numbers, you can have long vectors in this subspace as long as you want.